# how to set unidirectional one-to-one relationship using hibernate annotation on a non-primary key?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, join

i have set an unidirectional one-to-one mapping tables. here is my simplified version of its implementation.

```
// part of parent table called "Person"
@Id
@Column(name="id")
private String id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName = "person_id")
private PersonDetails details;
```

and then...

```
// part of child table called "PersonDetails"
@Id
@Column(name="id")
private String Id;

@Column(name="person_id")
private String personId;
```

this does not seem to work because hibernate sql log shows that hibernate is trying to do a join on Person and PersonDetails on " Person.Id=PersonDetails.Id" when what i really want is "Person.Id=PersonDetails.personId".

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should move the owning side into PersonDetails and use an inverse side into Person. This will imply using a bidirectional association but I've been successfully using this pattern in one of my previous projects:

Person:

```
// part of parent table called "Person"
@Id
@Column(name="id")
private String id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private PersonDetails details;
```

PersonDetails:

```
@Id
@Column(name="id")
private String Id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="person_id")
private Person person;
```

Comment: yeah this is something i wanted to avoid. bidirectional is easier and more intuitive to set up. but i specifically wanted to create one-to-one mapping unidirectionally using non-primary key. in any case, i had to bite the bullet and change my schema so that both tables would have 'id' as primary key where one is a foreign key to other. i don't like it but it works for the time being.